# My MBP keeps freezing

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, memory, performance

my mac had a keyboard problem and i had to change it. well i realised later that the "w" key behaves like its held so every time i have to deactivate it after turning the mac on with the virtual keyboard. Now the craziness is that few minutes after usage the mac freezes (screen turns blue, or other colors) and have to off it the hard way. when i turn it back on nothing would show on the screen as in totally black and it makes a continuous beeping sound (actually more than 5). i have to leave the mac for like hours before it would on properly again. and the same scenario restarts.what can be the problem? NEED YOUR HELP PLEASE :(

PS: i use a macbook pro 2.4GHz intel Core 2 Duo / 4GGb memory. OS Maverick

Comment: And oh i think i also have to specify that my battery needs to be replaced so the charger is the only power source

Comment: Why not take the w-key out temporarily to see if that solves the issue. Also try to use a different os x partition if you have one installed or maybe a linux partition on an external hdd to see if the current behaviour is apparent.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear to me but did you replace the keyboard with the defective "w" or does the replacement keyboard have the "w" issue?

The reason being, holding down a key, any key, will cause strange things to happen. An electronic issue with a Mac's (or really any computer's) keyboard can cause all sorts of strange problems.

Can you disconnect the keyboard and attach an external one (and will that even work?)?

A Bad battery can cause issues as well. try removing the battery (if possible) and running it on power without the battery in the Mac. That works on a number of older MacBooks/Powerbooks, hopefully it will work on yours.

And once the battery is out reset the SMC as per this Apple KB article http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964